# Calculate coordinates based on distance and direction

Tags: javascript

Here's my handy scheme:

[image]

Given:

- This is 2D, no third axis to worry about
- Segment `AB`, `A` and `B` both having `x` and `y` coordinates
- Side `width`, distance to each corner: `width / 2`
- `direction` in degrees (0 is up, 90 right, 180 down, etc)

How to calculate `x` and `y` coordinates for corners `1-4`?

---

```js
const A = {x: 0, y: 0};
const B = {x: 10, y: 0};
const direction = 90;
const width = 10;
const halfWidth = width / 2;

// tried the following one that I found but
// no lock, I assume somethings off with angles
function getCorner(point, angle, length) {
  return {
    x: point.x + Math.cos(angle) * length,
    y: point.y + Math.sin(angle) * length
  };
}

// EXPECTED
// bottom left: {x: 0, y: 5}
// bottom right: {x: 0, y: -5}
// top left: {x: 10, y: 5}
// top right: {x: 10, y: -5}

console.log(
  "bottom left:", 
  getCorner(A, direction - 90, halfWidth)
);
console.log(
  "bottom right:", 
  getCorner(A, direction + 90, halfWidth)
);

console.log("---");

console.log(
  "top left:", 
  getCorner(B, direction - 90, halfWidth)
);
console.log(
  "top right:", 
  getCorner(B, direction + 90, halfWidth)
);
```

Comment: Is length 2*width? The diagram doesn't look to scale.

Comment: @zer00ne Length of `AB` segment? Or length attr in `getCorner`? I named it poorly, should be `halfWidth`.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice AB there...

Comment: @zer00ne Yup, I only have `width`, `AB` segment and direction of segment (from A to B).

Comment: not clear what are inputs? if we have (x,y) of both A and B and distance width, then direction will also determined

Comment: @S.Serpooshan `x,y` for `A` and `B`, `width` (from 1 to 2 and 3-4, A and B are always at the center of `width`) and direction of `AB` segment (about 40 degrees in diagram, 0 is up, 90 is right).

Comment: how are x and y axis drawn? eg: y from top to bottom or reverse? i can't understand your Expected Result values! is direction the angle to rotate or it just specify the current slope of AB (nothing to rotate?)

Comment: @S.Serpooshan From bottom to top `y` axis. I made a mistake when I added different values to my code example (compared to diagram), I thought I made it simpler by avoiding awkward degree values. `direction` only shows the segment direction, nothing to rotate here. Fortunately I managed to solve this, see my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With indicating that Y axis is upward, it could be simply solved as following:

[image]

We see that each corner point is located at angle +/- 90 deg around the AB segment. consider the following figure, `dx` and `dy` values (to reach from A or B to each corner point) are easily calculated:

```
dx = (W/2).sin(alpha)
dy = (W/2).cos(alpha)
```

Where `alpha` is equal to `90 - direction`. So, we can write the js code as following snippet:

```js
const A = {x: 0, y: 0};
const B = {x: 10, y: 0};
const direction = 90;
const width = 10;

var length = width / 2;
var angle = (90 - direction) * (Math.PI / 180);

var dx = Math.sin(angle) * length;
var dy = Math.cos(angle) * length;

console.log( "bottom left:", {x: A.x - dx, y: A.y + dy} );
console.log( "bottom right:",  {x: A.x + dx, y: A.y - dy} );
console.log("---");
console.log( "top left:",  {x: B.x - dx, y: B.y + dy} );
console.log( "top right:",  {x: B.x + dx, y: B.y - dy} );
```

Comment: Thanks for not giving up, it's a lot more efficient than mine. I did however found a little mistake: `top right` should be  `{x: B.x + dx, y: B.y - dy}`. Current implementation works if `direction` is close to 90 but falls apart otherwise.

Comment: you are welcome! yes, it was a simple mistake, the proper math can be seen easily from the figure. and the formula pattern are the same for bottom and top (x-dx, y+dy and x+dx, y-dy). I edited this to rectify it, you can mark it as accepted answer now ;D.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out, so many different ways online and none worked. Trial and error won the day.

---

```js
const A = {x: 0, y: 0};
const B = {x: 10, y: 0};
const direction = 90;
const width = 10;
const halfWidth = width / 2;

// changed only this function
function getCorner(point, angle, length) {
  angle = angle * (Math.PI / 180);

  return {
    x: point.x + Math.sin(angle) * length,
    y: point.y + Math.cos(angle) * length
  };
}

// EXPECTED
// bottom left: {x: 0, y: 5}
// bottom right: {x: 0, y: -5}
// top left: {x: 10, y: 5}
// top right: {x: 10, y: -5}

console.log(
  "bottom left:", 
  getCorner(A, direction - 90, halfWidth)
);

// here's an error with JS or something, because
// "x: 6.123233995736766e-16" which is
// "0.0000000000000006123233995736766"
console.log(
  "bottom right:", 
  getCorner(A, direction + 90, halfWidth)
);

console.log("---");

console.log(
  "top left:", 
  getCorner(B, direction - 90, halfWidth)
);
console.log(
  "top right:", 
  getCorner(B, direction + 90, halfWidth)
);
```